# CircleCI timeout on app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

I try to run the build of my app and execute the espresso test with CI circle on my bitbucket account but I get a timeout (I have already increased to 2h and it still does not work) and gradle stop on

```
> Building 63%> Building 64% > :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
command ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex took more than 120 minutes to run
```

I have tried several solutions found on the internet but none helped me ..... I want to specify that the buid works very well on my pc (ArchLinux and Windows 10)

**My circle.yml**

```
#
# Build configuration for Circle CI
#

general:
  build_dir: my_app

machine:
    environment:
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
        GRADLE_OPTS: '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"'
        _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"
        ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT: "20"
        ANDROID_API_LEVEL: 25
        ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION: 25.0.3

dependencies:
    cache_directories:
        - ~/.gradle
        - ~/.android
        - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras

    pre:
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/tools" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION"; fi
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL"; fi
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-google_play_services"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
        # Android Tools latest (has sdkmanager)
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"; fi
          # ConstraintLayout
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2" ]; then echo y | /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.2"; fi
          # ConstraintLayout Solver
        - if [ ! -d "$ANDROID_HOME/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.0.2" ]; then echo y | /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.2"; fi
        - chmod +x gradlew

    override:
        - ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies

test:
  override:
    # start the emulator
    - emulator -avd circleci-android24 -no-window -gpu off:
        background: true
        parallel: true
    # wait for it to have booted
    - circle-android wait-for-boot
    # unlock the emulator screen
    - sleep 30
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    # run tests  against the emulator.
    - echo $PATH
    - ls
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex:
        timeout: 7200
    # copy the build outputs to artifacts
    - cp -r app/build/outputs $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
    # copy the test results to the test results directory.
    - cp -r app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
```

**My build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            //On renome le fichier mapping de proguard
            if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
                variant.assemble.doLast {
                    copy {
                        from variant.mappingFile
                        into output.outputFile.parent + "/mapping"
                        rename { String fileName ->
                            "mapping-${variant.name}-${variant.versionCode}-${new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd')}.txt"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //Renomage du fichier de sortie
            output.outputFile = new File(
                    output.outputFile.parent,
                    output.outputFile.name.replace("app-${variant.name}.apk", "app-${variant.name}-${variant.versionCode}.apk")
            )
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        Keys {
            private
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Keys
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Keys
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
}

setProperty("FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath", rootProject.rootDir.absolutePath + FirebaseServiceAccountFilePath)

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'

    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'

    compile 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:1.8.2'

    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.3'

    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'

    //Fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //Achat in app
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'com.github.iammert:MaterialIntroView:1.6.0'

    //Onglet
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'

    //Graphique
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'

    //Divers
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'

    //LeakCanary
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'

    //Sécurité de l'appli
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:PiracyChecker:1.0.2'

    //Recuperer les infos du playstore
    compile 'com.andrognito.rxmagneto:rxmagneto:1.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.7'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
//    compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.2.7.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3-alpha', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.3-alpha', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    //SqlScout
    compile 'com.idescout.sql:sqlscout-server:2.0'

    //Animation liste
    compile 'com.willowtreeapps.spruce:spruce-android:1.0.1'

    //Overlay
    debugCompile 'com.ms-square:debugoverlay:1.0.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.ms-square:debugoverlay-no-op:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'com.ms-square:debugoverlay-no-op:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This looks like to a problem with Crashlytics(Fabric) buildToolsVersion not found